# Am I a spellcaster if I take Magic Initiate or Ritual Caster feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, feats

If I take either the Magic Initiate or Ritual Caster feat, would I be considered a spellcaster for the purpose of attuning to magic items like the Wand of Lightning Bolts?

Comment: The question linked to as a duplicate of this doesn't have an accepted answer; the top-rated one claims to be invalidated, but gives an invalid poster's name as the one that _should_ be accepted. I'm not sure this should be counted as already having been answered under these circumstances.

Comment: @Polisurgist I suggest you upvote [the correct answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76560/27327) in the linked Q so that it becomes the top answer. The new current [top answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76505/27327) is also correct.

Comment: @Polisurgist an accepted answer really only means that that's the answer the asker found most useful or the best solution to their problem. It doesn't necessarily mean it's the absolute correct one. Also, thanks to this question being marked as a dup, the other Q is getting more attention and (potentially) more votes to sort out the answers. And it's worth noting that the user who asked the linked Q has been MIA on this site since before those answers came in.