# Is a Barbarian Totem Warrior a Spellcaster?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting

At third level, a Barbarian can take the Path of the Totem Warrior, gaining (among others), the following feature:

> **Spirit Seeker**
>
> Yours is a path that seeks attunement with the natural world, giving you a kinship with beasts. At 3rd level when you adopt this path, you gain the ability to cast the Beast Sense and Speak with Animals spells, but only as rituals.

**Is a Barbarian Totem Warrior a Spellcaster, for the purpose of using magic items that require attunement by a Spellcaster?**

**If so, what is the spellcasting ability of a Totem Warrior, for the purpose of using magic items?**

The [following question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53836/what-is-a-spellcaster-for-the-purpose-of-magic-item-attunement) and answers gloss over this particular case, but without giving a definitive answer for it.

Comment: The other question is a less specified version of this and the answer is applicable to this case too.

Comment: If you want to focus on the part of your question that is about what spellcasting ability to use, then you could ask that question specifically.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCoffron, I did so here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153634/what-is-the-spellcasting-ability-of-a-barbarian-totem-warrior